# How to make individual cells bold in kable table R markdown?

Tags: r-markdown, kable, bold

Here is a table I have created. I just want to make it stand out a little bit.
I have figured out how to make rows different colours. I know how to make an entire row or column bold (column_spec(5:7, bold = T)) but I would like specific cells only based on highest value...so for example in my table, I would like 147 in bold under number, 2.36 under mean....etc

Is there a way of doing this? Using conditional logic would be even better if that was possible - but I can't find how it is done?

Thanks

[image: My table]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - pretty simple:

```
test.attempt[1, 5] <- cell_spec(test.attempt[1, 5], "latex", bold = T)
```